# Redux Error: TypeError: state.favorites.concat is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I am using redux toolkit and ran into an issue where I cannot push the results into an array which I declared. This is my initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  favorites: [],
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
};
```

In the dashboard of my application, I want to display the favorites that are in state in which I use a useEffect as such:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
      console.log(message);
    }

    if (!user) {
      navigate("/login");
    }

    //dispatch(getFavorites());

    // return () => {
    //   dispatch(reset());
    // };
  }, [user, navigate, isError, message, dispatch]);
```

The problem occurs when I uncomment the dispatch to get favorites, here is the getFavorites in my service:

```
//Get user favorites
const getFavorites = async (token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  const response = await axios.get(API_URL, config);

  return response.data;
};
```

Here is how I create a favorite:

```
const createFavorite = async (favoriteData, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  var qs = require("qs");

  var data = qs.stringify({
    address: favoriteData.location["address1"],
    phone: favoriteData.display_phone,
    rating: favoriteData.rating.toString(),
    price: favoriteData.price,
  });

  console.log(favoriteData);
  const response = await axios.post(API_URL, data, config);

  return response.data;
};
```

This is where the error occurs in the slice file where my extra-reducers are:

```
export const favoriteSlice = createSlice({
  name: "favorite",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(createFavorite.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(createFavorite.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.favorites.concat(action.payload);
      })
      .addCase(createFavorite.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getFavorites.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getFavorites.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.favorites = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getFavorites.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      });
  },
});
```

The errors occurs on the line:
state.favorites.concat(action.payload)

Am I returning the data in a wrong format? I am new to redux and am following a tutorial so I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`.concat()` doesn't mutate it returns a copy so you have to also have to reset your state.favorites to it here:

```
  .addCase(createFavorite.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.isLoading = false;
    state.isSuccess = true;
    state.favorites = state.favorites.concat(action.payload);
  })
```

As for the error, it seems your state.favorites either goes undefined or its set to a non-array/string value. `.concat()` only works on arrays or strings

Comment: yes, I have determined that state.favoritees is undefined but do you have any clues as to why that is?

Comment: Probably by the `getFavorites.fulfilled` case. Since by default it's an array it seems to change after that.